# how to convert json for angularjs

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

how to convert this json

```
[{"categories":[{"id":"171","name":"Fashion"},{"id":"219","name":"Blog"}]}]
```

to

```
[{"id":"171","name":"Fashion"},{"id":"219","name":"Blog"}]
```

for angularjs data binding

Comment: `myObject[0]["categories"]` ?

Answer (score 2):

Your data is already in JSON format. You only require to read correct property.

```
var data = [{"categories":[{"id":"171","name":"Fashion"},{"id":"219","name":"Blog"}]}]  

var desired = data[0].categories; //Or data[0]["categories"]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
angular.fromJson(json);
```

Look [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.fromJson)